# In Catholic understanding, did Paul speak/write ex cathedra while Peter was serving as Pope?

Tags: catholicism, scriptures, papal-infallibility

Catholic doctrine teaches that Peter was the first Pope and that Popes may speak "ex cathedra".  When they do, that is considered infallible.

However, while Peter was alive and presumably serving as the first Pope, Paul, John, and James all wrote books that are considered to be Scripture.  In fact, Peter himself refers to Paul's letters as Scripture:

> and regard the patience of our Lord as salvation; just as also our
>   beloved brother Paul, according to the wisdom given him, wrote to you,
>   16 as also in all his letters, speaking in them of these things, in
>   which are some things hard to understand, which the untaught and
>   unstable distort, as they do also the rest of the Scriptures, to their
>   own destruction.  2 Peter 3:15-16 NAS

Were other people besides the Pope, then, able to speak/write ex cathedra while not serving as Pope?  If so, can others besides the Pope speak/write ex cathedra today?  What is the Catholic understanding of this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Ex cathedra](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/05677a.htm) means *from the chair* literally. It refers to the power of the reigning Pope to speak infallibly on doctrinal or moral issues. And although, in my understanding, the power of speaking "from the chair" *in general* is not a concept necessarily new to Catholicism (think of any leader speaking officially from their official seat), in Catholicism it refers specifically to the Pope's authority to make infallible proclamations.

Regarding the letters of Paul, John, and James, we believe that they're inspired writings. But, they're authoritative, per se -- at least not in the same manner of the authority granted by speaking *ex cathedra*. They're authoritative, if at all, in an *unordinary* manner. That is, their authority doesn't flow from a natural **seat** of authority, but from a supernatural infusion of God's grace. I think it's also accurate to say that their authority *within the Church* flowed from Peter. Their words were binding on Christians only to the extent than Peter bound them.

The authority of speaking *ex cathedra*, though infused with grace, is an *ordinary* authority. That is, it is in the nature of the office of Pope to be able to speak *ex cathedra*. The ability isn't absent until God inspires the Pope to speak *ex cathedra*; it's always there, regardless of whether the Pope actually *is* speaking *ex cathedra* (which is almost never).